# ASP.NET MVC Remote Validation lost submit button name

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 submit buttons in a form, to identify which button is clicked, the attribute "name" will serve the purpose

```
<input id="saveButton" type="submit" value="@Button.Save" name="ButtonType" />
<input id="saveAddNewButton" type="submit" value="@Button.SaveAndAddNew" name="ButtonType" />
```

And then the SubmitForm can get the "ButtonType" value

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitForm(MyModel model, FormCollection formCollection, string ButtonType)
{...
```

Also, I have a hidden field to store the LastUpdateDate value, and to validate whether the record has been updated by another user, so I use Remote Validation.

MyModel.cs

```
[Remote("isUpdate", "Check", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "The record has been changed by another user.")]
public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
```

.cshtml

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastUpdatedDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}", htmlAttributes: new { id="LastUpdatedDate", @type = "hidden" })
```

Without using Remote validation, I can get the ButtonType value. As such, I guess the submit action is triggered programmatically instead of by button clicked. Can anyone suggest how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Not clear what your trying to do. Why do your have parameters `MyModel model` and `FormCollection formCollection` in the post method? Why try to render a hidden field like that (`@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LastUpdatedDate)` is all you need)? `[Remote]` validation is not triggered on hidden fields so what is the point. What is the actual problem your trying to solve?

Comment: As the remote validation is ajax checking, and I don't want to do this checking during post-back, so I am going to take advantage of remote validation to block the form submission if the current record has been modified by another user. The validation can be done on hidden field with this code `$("#form").validate().settings.ignore = ":hidden:not([id*=LastUpdatedDate])";`
And the main purpose of using this validation is easily to copy the same logic to another actions.

Comment: And how would you trigger it (remote validation is triggered when the value is changed and is not empty!)?. Just intercept the `form.submit` and make an ajax call to a method that returns your validation result, then either cancel the submit or allow it to continue.

Comment: Actually, as I run the code, I can trigger the validation...I will take your advice to intercept the form.submit, thanks.